# integral representation of matrix logarithm

Tags: integration, matrices

Consider the following integral representation of $ln(X)$:
$$\ln(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{1+t}I - (X+tI)^{-1}]dt.$$
I do not understand how they derived this formula.

The only formula I found is $\ln(A) = (A-I)\int_{0}^{1}[s(A-I)+I]^{-1}ds$ from page 13 in the link [http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph251/exp19.pdf](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph251/exp19.pdf)

I appreciate if someone could send a reference of this formula, or its derivation. Thank you

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Intuitively, this is nothing but the matrix-version of the following identity

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}  \left( \frac{1}{1+t} - \frac{1}{\lambda + t} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t = \log \lambda $$

for $\lambda$ in $ \Omega := \mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty, 0]$. In light of functional calculus, this identity will remain true if we replace $\lambda$ by a square matrix $X$ with all of its eigenvalues lying in $\Omega$.

Let $\mathcal{X}_n$ denote the set of all $n\times n$ complex matrices for which the eigenvalues lie in $\Omega$.

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution.** Note that the set of all diagonalizable $X \in \mathcal{X}_n$ is dense in $\mathcal{X}_n$ and the integral in question is continuous on $\mathcal{X}_n$, it suffices to prove the claim when $X$ is diagonalizable. Then the general case follows by the continuity argument.

If $X \in \mathcal{X}_n$ is diagonalizable, we may write $X = P\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_k:1\leq k\leq n)P^{-1}$ for some invertible $P$ and for $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty, 0]$. Then

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( (1 + t)^{-1}I - (X + tI)^{-1} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= P \operatorname{diag}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty}  \left( \frac{1}{1+t} - \frac{1}{\lambda_k + t} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t : 1 \leq k \leq n \right) P^{-1} \\
&= P \operatorname{diag}\left( \log \lambda_k : 1 \leq k \leq n \right) P^{-1} \\
&= \log X.
\end{align*}

Therefore the desired identity follows.

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution.** By the holomorphic functional calculus, for each $X \in \mathcal{X}_n$,

$$ \log X = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\Gamma} (z I - T)^{-1} \log(z) \, \mathrm{d}z $$

for any piecewise-smooth simple closed curve $\Gamma \subset \Omega$ enclosing all the eigenvalues of $X$. Since $\log(I) = 0$, we may as well write

$$ \log X = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\Gamma} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z, \qquad f(z) := \left[ (z I - T)^{-1} - (zI - I)^{-1} \right] \log(z). $$

This makes the integrand decay fast enough as $z \to \infty$, namely

$$ \left\| f(z) \right\| = \mathcal{O}\biggl( \frac{\log\left|z\right|}{\left|z\right|^2} \biggr) \quad\text{as } \left|z\right|\to\infty. $$

So by deforming the contour $\Gamma$ in the shape of keyhole contour surrounding the branch cut $(-\infty, 0]$ and letting the radius to infinity, only the infinite contour surrounding the branch cut remains, yielding

\begin{align*}
\log X
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \biggl( \int_{-\infty + 0^+i}^{0^+i} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z + \int_{- 0^+i}^{-\infty-0^+i} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z \biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{\infty} \bigl( f(-t + 0^+i) - f(-t - 0^+i) \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( -(t I + T)^{-1} + (tI + I)^{-1} \right)  \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

In the third line, we used the fact that $\log(-t + 0^+i) - \log(-t - 0^+i) = 2\pi i$ for $t > 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The answer is great. I am still trying to read and understand it.